# Does the EMH ever laugh?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh

From time to time the EMH seems to "chuckle," usually because he's made a clever comment. I'm referring here to genuine laughter (as genuine as a computer program can laugh; no need to split hairs and say that the EMH can't really laugh).

[image]

Comment: This question made me think of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPInEwhGwHA).

Comment: Actually I can't think of many instances of where Star Trek characters laugh more than a chuckle.

Comment: I assume the pun was intentional

Comment: @zabeus Q briefly gifts Data with the ability to genuinely and heartily laugh.  And I'm sure there are quite a lot of other instances where gases or aliens etc. result in forced laughter.

Comment: @zabeus There's some TOS episode where they defeat the alien of the week by laughing at it. Maybe the one with the female Klingon.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yep I remember Picard drawing the smiley face on the cloud of laughing gas. TOS had more examples, but it seems laughing is usually associated with something bad happening. Then there's [the Klingons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qe-RQ79RKG4&list=PLHLujzHjIdQ3t1P-plMKQr0ba_M4Uy3DV).

Comment: Riker, Picard, and Wes laugh heartily when Crusher gets nailed with a banana split. (Frankly, I think this is the funniest scene in all of Star Trek.)

Comment: Doesn't count, but this is what it would look like; https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0d/70/b0/0d70b0655eaa43a0d60d14cbe277302e.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Season 4, Episode 5 [*Revulsion*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Revulsion_(episode)) you can hear (and briefly see) the EMH laughing at Tom and Harry's idiotic story about a prank they play on Tuvok. But it isn't much more than a chuckle.

[image: EMH chuckling]

Comment: I've added an image of the chuckle in so it's easier to see without watching the clip.

Comment: Live long and prosper

Comment: This is probably the best answer. While EMH is arguably more stoic than Captain Picard, he is certainly more lighthearted than Tuvok or Spock (especially if you disregard the "space hippies" episode). Thanks.